# C# Getting JSON-encoded dictionary along with erroneous status code with HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, json, json.net, httpwebresponse

I've been coding a Minecraft session library. Basically, it has methods such as Authenticate() and Refresh() to get access tokens for launchers to use ([source](https://bitbucket.org/ilan321/minelib/wiki/Home)). One of the methods, `PostHTTP()`, takes 2 parameters and outs one (JObject JSON, string endpoint, out int statuscode [for debug reasons]). The proper method name is:

```
public static string PostHTTP(JObject JSON, string endpoint, out int statusCode)
```

Now, when the program, for example, uses Authenticate (the launcher does *not* use the `PostHTTP()` method directly, but it is used by other methods such as `Authenticate()`) and supplies a username and password, the `Authenticate()` method parses the user/pass combo into a JSON.NET `JObject`, and sends it along to `PostHTTP()`, like so:

```
public static string Authenticate(string username, string password, out int statusCode)
{
    JObject toPost = new JObject(
        new JProperty("agent",
            new JObject(
                new JProperty("name", "Minecraft"),
                new JProperty("version", 1))),
        new JProperty("username", username),
        new JProperty("password", password));
    return PostHTTP(toPost, "authenticate", out statusCode);
}
```

In the `PostHTTP()` method, this is the current code:

```
public static string PostHTTP(JObject JSON, string endpoint, out int statusCode)
{ // endpoint = authenticate, invalidate, etc.
    string response = null;
    try
    {
        var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Vars.AuthServer + endpoint);
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        req.Method = "POST";
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sw.Write(JSON.ToString());
            sw.Flush();
            sw.Close();

            var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(response);
            statusCode = (int)resp.StatusCode;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException)
    {
        statusCode = 69;
        return null;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Now, for example the user inputs a wrong username/password combo. The auth server will return:

- An appropriate, non-200 HTTP status code
- A JSON-encoded dictionary with this format:

  {
    "error": "Short description of the error",
    "errorMessage": "Longer description which can be shown to the user",
    "cause": "Cause of the error"        // optional
  }

The problem is that the code, as of now, only catches the status code and its message (`The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden`).
**How do I catch the JSON dictionary along with the status code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is [`WebException.Response` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx). It will be not null if some response was received with error status code.

P.S. You can remove `sw.Flush` and `sw.Close` calls, and move the code after them (from `GetResponse` to setting `statusCode`) outside of `using (sw)`. You should also dispose `resp`.

Comment: I named the WebException `x`, and I wrote `Console.WriteLine(x.Response.ToString());` but it only says `System.Net.HttpWebResponse`, not the JSON that's sent along.

Comment: `WebException.Response` needs to be handled exactly like you're handling `WebRequest.GetResponse()`. It's the same complex object, not just a response string.

Comment: Wow, I figured it all out myself by looking at my old TCP shit program :) Thanks for the help! (I used x.Response.GetResponseStream().Read() to get the string)